# bootstrap nav getting cut in half on mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have no idea what is going on here. In firefox on mobile size view it works perfectly but for some reason it cuts off when using it on mobile.

You can find the website [here](http://rentcoach.net/).

[image: cut off]

Comment: On my mobile, it works fine.

Comment: Looks fine from my mobile as well.

Comment: Did you use some online tester? If so, this might be messing your page up. That, or some CSS did not load properly.

Comment: might be a windows phone issue then. I have 2 different browsers on it and both seem to be giving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that i believe IE 9 and higher don't support the `@media(max-width:767px)`.
I have found the answer [here](http://trentwalton.com/2013/01/16/windows-phone-8-viewport-fix/).